# can we create multiple routes with same name in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route exact path="*" element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" />} />
    <Route element={<SuperadminRoute />}>
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" element={<Mycomponent />} />
    </Route>
    <Route element={<AdminRoute />}>
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" element={<Mycomponent />} />
    </Route>
    <Route element={<UserRoute />}>
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" element={<Mycomponent />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

**Update:**  See all the parent components SuperadminRoute, AdminRoute, UserRoute are private routes and one cannot access the routes of another parent route. They have the code to check authorzation. And what CheckAuth should do to prevent one role to do not enter into another one's route. So Can I little simplify it?

superadmin.js

```
const SuperadminRoute = () => {

  return isAuthenticated ? (
    <CheckAuth applicableTo={USER_TYPES.ADMIN} role={user?.role}>
      {lodar && !user && !streamStates && !totalProcessingLimit ? (
        <Spin indicator={antIcon} className="loader__full" />
      ) : (
        <>
          <Header/>
          <Outlet }} />
        </>
      )}
    </CheckAuth>
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" />
  );
};
export default SuperadminRoute;
```

Like above I have same condition in other admin.js and user.js

admin.js

```
return (
  <div>
    <CheckAuth applicableTo={USER_TYPES.ADMIN} role={user?.role}>
      <Header2 />
      <Outlet />
    </CheckAuth>
  </div>
)
```

user.js

```
return (
  <div>
    <CheckAuth applicableTo={USER_TYPES.USER} role={user?.role}>
      <Header3 />
      <Outlet />
    </CheckAuth>
  </div>
)
```

checkAuth.js

```
const CheckAuth = ({ applicableTo, role, children }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [isRenderChildren, setIsRenderChildren] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (applicableTo && role) {
      switch (applicableTo) {
        case USER_TYPES.ADMIN:
          if (role !== ROLE.SUPERADMIN && role !== ROLE.SUPERADMIN) {
            return navigate("/dashboard");
          }
          break;
        case USER_TYPES.USER:
          if (role !== ROLE.SUPER_ADMIN && role !== ROLE.ADMIN && role !== ROLE.USER) {
            return navigate("/dashboard");
          }
          break;
        default:
          return navigate("/login");
      }
      setIsRenderChildren(true);
    }
  }, [role]);
  return <>{isRenderChildren ? children : null}</>;
};
export default CheckAuth;
```

In all my parent components i.e. SuperadminRoute, Admin, UserRoute we have different headers and that is why I do not want to make a separate container for the common routes because I have to put conditions for the headers. So is it possible to create route with same name and whoever the role logged in should redirect to their route?

Comment: No, it's not possible. React router will find the first match and use that

Comment: You can only ever have 1 exact matched route. This won't work as only the first route will be rendered. These 3 routes all have the same rank/specificity. What are you wanting to use to differentiate them so the correct header is rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't render multiple routes with the same rank score, only the first match will be rendered. If you need to conditionally render different headers on a set of routes then do this conditional check in the layout route.

Example:

```
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const isAuthenticated = /* wherever isAuthenticated comes from */;

  if (lodar && !user && !streamStates && !totalProcessingLimit) {
    return <Spin indicator={antIcon} className="loader__full" />;
  }

  return isAuthenticated
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
```

```
const Layout = () => {
  const user = /* wherever user comes from */;

  return (
    <>
      <CheckAuth applicableTo={USER_TYPES.SUPER_ADMIN} role={user?.role}>
        <Header />
      </CheckAuth>
      <CheckAuth applicableTo={USER_TYPES.ADMIN} role={user?.role}>
        <Header2 />
      </CheckAuth>
      <CheckAuth applicableTo={USER_TYPES.USER} role={user?.role}>
        <Header3 />
      </CheckAuth>

      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};
```

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/dashboard" />} />
    <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
      <Route element={<Layout />}>
        <Route path="dashboard">
          <Route index element={<Mycomponent />} />
          ... other "/dashboard/..." routes
        </Route>

        ... other "Layout" routes
        <Route path="user-management" element={...} />
        <Route path="user-listing" element={...} />
      </Route>

      ... other protected routes
    </Route>

    ... other non-"Layout" routes
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer few questions I have. 1) You have given path "/dashboard" to the parent route instead of every child. What does it do? 2) I have few more common components to render like "/user-mangament" & "/user-listing" so where I can put those routes?

Comment: @Profer (1) This is how you build relative routes, e.g. `Dashboard` is rendered on `"/dashboard"`, and if there was another route, say `<Route path="admin" element={<AdminArea />} />` then `AdminArea` is rendered on `"/dashboard/admin"`. (2) Are these other "dashboard" routes, or do they just need to have the `DashboardLayout` as a parent route? You can move the `path="dashboard"` down if you need sibling routes. Does this all make sense? I'll tweak my answer to see if this is clearer.

Comment: Could you please check the updated question. I tried to explain what I have done.

Comment: @Profer I suggest splitting the logic of route protection from the logic of conditionally rendering the appropriate header component based on user role. See if the latest edit is in the direction for what you are looking for.